# Better than O(n) glob matcher?

Tags: c++, algorithm, glob

**The problem:** Given a list of [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), I need to find (and return) a glob from the list that a given string matches or definitively determine that none match in. Excluding setup time, performance must be better than a linear search of all the globs:

```
foreach glob in list:
  if glob.matches(string):
    return glob
return None
```

***The question:** Are there any available libraries (C++ preferred) for this?*

---

Edit: After a bit more thought, I thinkin I can argue that this can be done. Given that globs are more or less regex with a different syntax, a runtime version of lex that uses glob syntax would fit the bill.

Given that the problem can be trivially reduced to a know problem, I'm only still interested in implemented solutions.

Comment: Is it even possible? Given 26 globs (`*A*`, `*B*`, `*C*`... `*Z*`) is it possible to not check all the 26 globs (so O(n))

Comment: xanatos: Given that set, you should expect to only needs to check a small number of globs before one matches. Or you could compress it to the regex `.*[A-Z].*` and run that.

Answer (score 7):

Convert your globs into regular expressions (a series of simple string manipulations can achieve this - `*` becomes `.*`, etc). Combine them into a single regular expression, using `|` and assigning the results to a different capture group for each glob so that you can determine which glob matched if there was a match. Rely on your favourite regex library to compile the regular expression into a DFA that is hopefully more optimal to process than a linear walk of the constituent parts, where this is possible - however, in the most general case, it will not be faster.

Comment: Wha? Given enough free startup time, any regex can be matched in `lenght(input)` time so it should be faster in any case with more than one glob. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you find which capture group was filled in less than `O(n)`?

Comment: @BCS: Any particular regex (which is really "regular"; some Perl "regex" syntaxes do not qualify) can be matched in O(length(input)) time, yes.  But when the length of the regex is also a relevant variable, you need a different model of computational complexity.

Comment: @BCS Won't regexes need to backtrack if the greedy part grabs too much at first? Additionally I think what @moonshadow is saying is that the constant of the linear search with a regex may make it as slow or slower than a corresponding linear search of the globs.

Comment: Your regex library will, in reality, create an NFA and use backtracking to select between alternative possibilities. While it is possible to convert an NFA to an equivalent DFA, real-world engines frequently don't bother. See e.g. http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: @Mark B: with a suitable DFA, it there is no need to ever backtrack (I'm asking for full-string match, not substring match so you don't need to worry about un-getting anything).

Comment: @moonshadow: My regex library for this class of problem will, in reality, become my *former* regex library as soon as a find it using an NFA and backtracking :ob

Answer (score 6):

Globs are a subset of regular expressions (with respect to expressive power, not exact syntax). Globs can therefore be converted into deterministic finite automata (DFA) and those can be combined to form a single DFA that recognizes the union of the single DFAs. DFAs have a complexity of O(n) with n being the length of the string. How much Globs the automaton is constructed from only influences the setup time (i.e. creating the automaton), not the run time.

Comment: I just noticed that an changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have better than linear time in the number of globs. In order to prove that a string doesn't match any of the globs, you have to check for a match against every one, or you'll never know whether one you skipped matched or not.

EDIT: In the general case this isn't possible using globs. As noted in a comment it's possible for some combinations of globs to be combined (At first guess a trie might be useful, where each node indicates the next letter to match and the globs you still need to check), causing a smaller amount of work searching.

It also might be possible in the general case to convert a set of globs into a corresponding regular expression.

Is performance of this matching really such an issue that you need to improve it? Have you considered if a more fundamental algorithmic rewrite might be better?

Comment: That assume that you can't combine some of the match efforts with some setup work: e.g. if `/foo/bar/*` doesn't match, for 5 places, `/foo/baz/*` need not be checked and if it fails after the second place, `/pickle/*` can be skipped.

Comment: Technically you could try to create a "negative" expression, one of "don't match". It COULD be simpler, but I'm not sure... I was looking for two non-simplifiable and not-negatable expressions... While the union of the globs is clearly O(n), perhaps the intersection of the negative globs is a little less.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just in some particular cases. If you can predict somehow that some globs will not match your string.

Answer (score 0):

I would look to see if your application is a good fit for a [shift-reduce parser](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~zdu/parsdemo/srintro.html) like [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).  They use lookup tables, which are a pain to set up or change and use more memory, but are very fast.  Technically, it's not physically possible to do better than O(n) *worst case*, but depending on your globs, your strings, and your tokenizer, using a technique like this can make your *average* case much better than that, because it eliminates patterns that *don't* match without having to check each one each time.

Comment: See this answere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434209/better-than-on-glob-matcher/5434304#5434304